# Passing multiple arrays from PHP to AJAX and JQuery Autocomplete with JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, autocomplete

Right now I'm trying to pass multiple arrays to my AJAX function with JSON so that it will display on the search suggestions. Yet whenever I tried to pass it, the JSON will always parse my data such that the keyword/search term will show up before the JSON arays so the parsing always failed. How can I remove this keyword? 
The parsing succeeded if  there were only one variable sent so I assumed that the problem lies with how I passed the arrays, but I couldn't figure out why. I'm using Codeigniter.

Thank you for your time.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchterm" name="searchterm">
```

PHP (Controller):

```
function search_produkTindakan(){
        if (isset($_GET['searchterm'])) {
            $cari=$this->input->get('searchterm');
        }
        $tindakan = array();
        $nama_jns_barang = array();
        $tindakan = $this->billing_m_pasien->pencariandata_tindakan($cari);
        $nama_jns_barang= $this->billing_m_pasien->pencariandata_produk($cari);
        echo json_encode(array('tindakan'=>$tindakan, 'nama_jns_barang'=>$nama_jns_barang));
    }
```

PHP (Model):

```
function pencariandata_tindakan($cari='')
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tindakan, kategori FROM daftar_tindakan WHERE tindakan LIKE '%$cari%'  OR kategori LIKE '%$cari%' "  );
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
          $muatData = $query->row();
          $data = array();
          // $data['tindakan'] = $muatData->tindakan;
          $query = $query->result_array();
          if( is_array($query) && count ($query) > 0 ){ 
            $n = 0;
            foreach ($query as $row ) 
            {
              $data['tindakan'.'['.$n.']'] = $row['tindakan'];
              $n++;
            }
          }
          asort($data);
          return $data;
        }
        else {
          echo $cari;
          // return false;
        }
      }
```

Javascript:

```
var caridata=$("#searchterm").val();
$("#searchterm").autocomplete({ 
source: function( request, response ) { 
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('bla');?>",
    type:"GET",
    data:"searchterm="+searchterm,
    dataType : 'json',
    cache:false,
    success: function( data ) {
        var tindakan = data[0];
        var nama_jns_barang = data[1];
        if(data!=null) {
            if (tindakan!=null) {
                response(tindakan);
            }
            else if (nama_jns_barang!=null) {
                response(nama_jns_barang);
            }
        }
        else {
            //
        }
        }, // end of success
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);            
     }  //end of error                          
                            }) // end of ajax
                    }, // end of source
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        $("#caridata").val(ui.item.id);
                    } // end of select
                }); // end of autocomplete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to pass multiple arrays yet, so for now I just grouped the search functions in my controller into one function and loaded the data in one array. It did the trick for now, but I'm still looking for answers.